# How to include js file in yii 2.0?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to use 3rd party js files in my application. I have little bit knowledge in Yii 1.1.

But I'm very new to Yii 2.0. Now i'm started working on Yii 2.0 advanced.

I tried with Yii official documentation but it's hard to understand.

Can anyone suggest me for Yii 2.0 reference book in simple manner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure there are any books as Yii2 has been released 2 months ago. I suggest searching on google and buy any of them if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good book for yii2 beginners, based upon the advanced template:
https://leanpub.com/yii2forbeginners/ (290 pages)

If you already have some experience with yii1 or yii2 and like the test driven developement I recommend this book (rewritten 3rd edition of a book which was already published on yii1 in two editions):
https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/web-application-development-yii-2-and-php/

Comment: Thanks fory. I need guidance for Yii 2.0. In my office no one have experienced in Yii 2.0. If you can guide me, can i get your email?